# Как правильно использовать @Modifying для метода класса?

Tags: spring, transaction

Нужно выполнить три хранимые процедуры бд postgres-13 в одной трансакции.
Сделал так:

- в компоненте @Service собрал вызов хранимых процедур в одном методе;
- пометил этот метод аннотацией  @Modifying;
  Конфигурационный файл не объявляет TransactionManager.
  JPA не используется, только spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc.

Конструкция работает, но я сомневаюсь в её правильности.
Кажется, что я что-то упускаю.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не нашел в документации, просто проверил и оказалось, что для соблюдения атомарности трансакции, нужно в методе @Service-класса объявить две аннотации:

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    public boolean methodTransaction
```